# Looping through a list of clicks in selenium python and gathering info

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I was able to use selenium to log into a scheduling website and click to the list of clients. Every client can be clicked on, to gather info about how many appointments they have left. What I want to do now is loop through all the clients, clicking on them, getting whatever info I need in an array or whatever (problem for later).

As of right now my main question would actually just be clicking on one client and then clicking on the next one until the list is complete. I can figure out the rest later.

How do I go about doing this? In previous questions I see that many people already have the list of URLs ready, here I obviously don't.

Comment: Update the question with your code trials and the text based relevant HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You can first fetch all the links you would want to click on by using
findElements method.
Then you will need a loop using foreach.
pseduo code will be
foreach(linkwebelement in listoflinks){
link.click
do your work
go back to page
}
you may come across in here stale element excpetion, if you do, you will need page handle again.
hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for this! I tried doing this but I’m only getting 1 element when it’s supposed to have 2. I did use find elements by xpath so it should have worked. Any idea why the other one didn’t count?

Comment: Recheck the locator which you are using to find the element, also if the other elements isn't under a frame or iframe. this may help.